# Como obtener una nueva columna mostrando porcentajes comparativos en un dataframe despues de groupby()

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Dispongo de una serie de datos que mediante el siguiente código he agrupado para organizar como necesito:

```py
dt = datos
dt['fecha'] = pd.to_datetime(dt['fecha'], format = '%Y/%m/%d')
agrup = datos.groupby(['almacen', dt.fecha.dt.year, dt.fecha.dt.month])['litros'].sum().unstack().unstack()
```

del cual obtengo el siguiente DataFrame que muestra los diferentes centros, el sumatorio de cada uno de los meses y en cada año:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Para mostrar la evolución de los datos del último año respecto a los del anterior querría añadir a cada subconjunto de meses para cada centro el porcentaje del año anterior que he cumplido de manera que se indique -100% si por ejemplo en Febrero (2) de 2020 no hay datos aun y si en Enero de 2020 en el centro 1, como se ve en la imagen el dato es de 2744176 respecto a 2726634 del año anterior se muestre +0.64% que es el % que ha crecido el volumen respecto a 2019 (lo hago aplicando un porcentaje superior a 100 y restando 100, idem para si fuese menor mostrar el porcentaje negativo).
El resultado que pretendo obtener es algo del siguiente tipo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

donde los elementos tachados corresponden a los centros de trabajo.
¿Cómo podría añadir esta nueva columna?
No adjunto el DataFrame completo porque es bastante grande y el dataframe obtenido tras el groupby que es el de la imagen oscura no permite hacer recortes sin perder información. Si fuese necesario podría buscar un medio para compartirlo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Por si fuera de ayuda para futuras consultas he conseguido hacer lo que pretendía. Para ello he trabajado de manera manual sobre la tabla empleando el Multindex, adjunto el código completo y espero que a alguien le sea útil:

```py
dt = datos
dt['fecha'] = pd.to_datetime(dt['fecha'], format = '%Y/%m/%d')
agrup = datos.groupby(['almacen', dt.fecha.dt.year, dt.fecha.dt.month])['litros'].sum().unstack().unstack()

indices = agrup.columns
years = np.unique(dt.fecha.dt.year)[-1:-3:-1]## cojo los dos ultimos años

years = np.sort(years)
datos_penultimo = []
datos_ultimo = []

#hasta aqui saco los datos de los ultimos años 
for i, j in indices:
    if j == years[0]:
        datos_penultimo.append(agrup[i,j])
    elif j == years[1]:
        datos_ultimo.append(agrup[i,j])
        
#calculo a partir de los datos los porcentajes



porcentajes  = []
for i,j in enumerate(a):
    a = datos_penultimo[i]
    b = datos_ultimo[i]
    calc = b/a*100-100
    calc = calc.fillna(-100) #relleno los datos vacios
    calc = calc.round() #redondeo el porcentaje
    porcentajes.append(calc)
    
    
porcentajes
for i,p in enumerate(porcentajes):
    agrup[int(i+1),'%'] = p
    agrup = agrup.sort_index(axis = 1)
```